# MySQL - How to add multiple values in a single column

Tags: c#, mysql, database-design, database-normalization

I have two tables (Subjects and Teachers tables). How can I link the subjects to the teacher, where a teacher can have multiple subjects. Also with the subjects, a subject can be multiple day in a week. How can I do that inside c#? Please help.

Comment: I don't want to make this an answer because I'm not certain it's correct, but I think you could add a column to the Subjects table that contains a Teacher's ID number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual solution to this would be to create an intermediate table or "intersection entity."

You're trying to create a many-to-many relationship between Subjects and Teachers, in that each Teacher can teach multiple Subjects and multiple Teachers can teach the same Subject. To get around this you create an intersection table which, for the sake of argument, we could call `Teaches`. Your schema would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE teachers
(
  id      CHAR(10)      PRIMARY KEY,
  name    VARCHAR(255)
  -- more fields
);

CREATE TABLE subjects
(
  id      CHAR(10)      PRIMARY KEY,
  name    VARCHAR(63)
  -- more fields
);

CREATE TABLE teaches
(
  teacher_id  CHAR(10) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES teachers (id),
  subject_id  CHAR(10) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES subjects (id),
  PRIMARY KEY (teacher_id, subject_id)
);
```

This transforms your many-to-many relationship into a pair of one-to-many relationships.

Your second problem, that of multiple classes per week for each subject, would most easily be handled with a single child table of `classes` with one record for each period a class meets. In both cases, the subject you want to research is "normalization."

Comment: @MatthewMoisen You should call it whatever makes the most sense to you, and is consistent with how you've named other stuff. :)

Comment: Add on `INDEX(subject_id, teacher_id)` since you will probably want to go the other way, too.

Comment: Don't use `CHAR` unless they are really fixed length.  Use `VARCHAR` instead.